# How can I tell if a site that looks like Stack Overflow is "official"?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, open-source

I recently came across a website which supports OpenID.
After I logged in to that web site, it said my account was successfully associated with the one I have at Stack Overflow.
The UI of that web site looks very similar to that of Stack Overflow.
My question is: what kind of open source application is Stack Overflow using?
I mean, I don't know if it is an open source application like phpBB.

Answer (score 10):

All sites in the Stack Exchange Network...

http://stackexchange.com

... have the gen-u-wine Stack Exchange branding in the upper left corner of the website.

[image]

**If you see this branding**, that means the site is an official part of our network.

If you don't, that means it is not affiliated with us.

Comment: "... that means it is not affiliated with us..." - either that or it's a scam - run!

Comment: Quite easy to fake an image in HTML, just sayin'

Comment: +1 @Tom but I think it might be a little harder to fake the viewable inbox messages which appear when you click in that branding.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow has a number of sister sites; they're listed at the bottom (scroll down!). You might find the site down there.

As for an open source version, check out Shapado. It's not exactly the same, but it does a decent job. Only downside is it's written in Ruby (unless you like Ruby, in which case hooray!)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapado

http://gitorious.org/shapado

http://shapado.com/

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this Stackoverflow blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/) which explains what SO was built with. But - will be moved to meta, probably.